# shutil.copy failure when the destination already exists and is read-only

Tags: python

I am using shutil.copy to copy files from one location to another.  If a file with the same name already exists in the destination location, it is normally ok and overwrites.  However, if the destination is read-only, it throws a permission denied error.

What is the most elegant way to deal with this?  Is there another shutil function that will deal with the permissions issue, or must I check the permissions on ever file I copy?

Comment: How would you expect that function to deal with the error?

Comment: By modifying the permissions, I suppose.

Comment: @coffee: I wouldn't want a normal "copy" utility to do this. First of: if I don't have permission to write to a file, chances are I don't have permission to change that permission and second: even if I *have* permission to change the permission, I'd want it to be an explicit act (in other words, if I remove write permission from one of my files, then I want it to stay untouched!).

Comment: Entirely reasonable.  Thus, the question!  I was wondering if there was an alternative shutil function that does this, something like shutil.force_copy() or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

smth like

```
import os
import shutil

def my_super_copy(what, where):
    try:
        shutil.copy(what, where)
    except IOError:
        os.chmod(where, 777) #?? still can raise exception
        shutil.copy(what, where)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check for permissions.  Let the OS tell you there's a permission problem and then deal with it. I'm assuming that the PermissionDeniedError is the exception you're getting so your solution would look something like this.

```
try:
  shutil.copy(blah,blah,blah)
except PermissionDeniedError:
  <Code for whatever you want to do if there arent sufficient permissions>
```